# html flow charts/ workflow diagram

Tags: javascript, html, workflow, flowchart

I have large set of flow charts and workflow diagrams. I want to draw them and convert them into a webpage, I also need every object in the flow chart to be clickable. I tried Visio and it does save the flow chart diagram as webpage. But I find the structure to be to be too complicated, with different level of file hierarchy with lot of javascript files and css files. 
I just know some basic html and javascript and I need just a simple static clickable flow chart. Is there a program to do such? I know that there are few javascript libraries like Raphel which can draw interactive flowcharts. But I donot want such fancy stuff, my flowcharts are very complex and I have to manually draw them and convert them into webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is just an image of the flowchart embedded in a webpage, with clickable areas, then an imagemap might just work for you.

You can save the flowchart image from Visio, powerpoint, photoshop or any such tool and then create an imagemap (it is a simple html code that allows you to execute code on click etc)

http://www.image-maps.com/
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap